# Insert in Cassandra is returning null pointer error

Tags: go, cassandra

Using Cassandra as follows to insert data, I am worried that the stuff that is initialized in `IntializeCassandra` is no longer around?

```
var csession gocql.Session 

func IntializeCassandra(){
    fmt.Println("Intializing Cassandra")
    cluster := gocql.NewCluster("10.0.0.60")
    cluster.Keyspace = "tickdata"
    cluster.Consistency = gocql.Quorum
    csession, _ := cluster.CreateSession()
    defer csession.Close()
}

func main() {
    IntializeCassandra()
}
```

Later in a function callback, when I try to insert the data into cassandra, I get a null pointer error

```
func msgHandler(src *net.UDPAddr, n int, b []byte) {
    t := time.Now().UTC()
    tformat := t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
    md := &MarketData.MD{}
    proto.Unmarshal(b[:n], md)
    log.Printf("%d %d %d %d %s %.5f %.5f", md.Firm, md.Symbol, md.Expiry, md.Id, tformat, md.Bid, md.Ask)
    if err := csession.Query(`INSERT INTO timeseries (firm, symbol, expiry, quote_id, time, bid, ask) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`,
         md.Firm, md.Symbol, md.Expiry, md.Id, tformat, md.Bid, md.Ask).Exec(); err != nil {
         log.Fatal(err)
    }


panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x594687]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want `defer csession.Close()` where it is. `csession.Close()` will be called when `IntializeCassandra`is about to return, so that will happen immediately.

EDIT: I just realized there's another big problem with this code. `csession, _ := cluster.CreateSession()` creates a local variable named `csession` which shadows the global variable. You should use `=` instead of `:=`.

Comment: No I figured it out. For some reason csession is not seen by the other functions. So I moved csession inside main, and then pass the pointer as a paramenter to the other functions.

Comment: `csession` should be visible anywhere in the package.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with code:
You should check for error here. If it fails, the don't proceed

```
csession, err := cluster.CreateSession()
if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Also you don't need defer session.Close() or session.Close() as it will invalidate and close your connection. Write defer session.Close() in main after returning session from IntializeCassandra to main(). Also you should have a global variable called Csession which can be used anywhere